How to double-click when developing a Chrome extension program?
What are the ways to use double click events?

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {if (tab) {toggleTabPin();}});
function toggleTabPin(tabId) {chrome.tabs.get(tabId, function(tab) {var newPinState = !tab.pinned;chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { pinned: newPinState });});}
function togglePinState() {chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {tabs.forEach(function(tab) {var newPinState = !tab.pinned;chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { pinned: newPinState });});});}
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {var metaKey = tab.metaKey || tab.ctrlKey;var shiftKey = tab.shiftKey;if (metaKey && shiftKey) {var newPinState = !tab.pinned;chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { pinned: newPinState });}});
function togglePinState() {chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {tabs.forEach(function(tab) {var newPinState = !tab.pinned;chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {pinned: newPinState});});});}
chrome.action.onDoubleClick.addListener(togglePinState);


There's no such event.
